# Cosmos db documents read string in lower

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

I using xamarin forms I would like to read document with Cosmosdb :

This query works I can match 2 string  u.Username in my cosmos db and MyFriendName my string

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyUser>(collectionLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
.Where(u =(u.Username.Contains(MyFriendName)) )// A voir 
.Take(30)
.AsDocumentQuery();
```

I would like to make a match with lower case but it is not working:

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyUser>(collectionLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
.Where(u =(u.Username.ToLower().Contains(MyFriendName.ToLower())) )// A voir 
.Take(30)
.AsDocumentQuery();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the older v2 .NET SDK? Support for case insensitive search is supported but only in the newer v3 .NET SDK. You can learn more here. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/new-string-function-performance-improvements-and-case-insensitive-search/

Comment: @hugokis Case Insensitive support is definitely in SDK 3.12.0, you can use he high version sdk to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the solution visible for others, posting the answer in comment here:

Case Insensitive support is definitely in SDK 3.12.0, need to upgrade to high version SDK